# using clearcanvas for dicom browser

Tags: c#, clearcanvas

I'm a beginner in using clearcanvas. I'm downloading a source code from clearnanvas page. I want to make a dicom browser. Could you suggest me how can i use this tool? I'm also beginner in programing. Could you suggest me any forums, pages or documentation?

Comment: @user: some hints: 1) you don't need to put "C#" in your title. It's in the tags, where it belongs. 2) On this site, you shouldn't use "Hey", "Thanks", or signatures. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Comment: and change your nickname to something more meaningful :)

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on what you want?  Also, have you looked at the DICOM browser in the ClearCanvas workstation?  Do you want to do something similar, and can you look at the code there?